# ValidationContext in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, validation

i was trying to do some validation based on blog[wcf validation](http://rahulrraj.blogspot.ae/2012/03/wcf-error-handling-using.html)

But i am not able to find a namespace for `ValidationContext` , i imported System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations but no luck at all.Any idea about this ?

Comment: When I import `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and adds `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` i can add [Required] on my model, without any problem, remove references and try again.

Comment: Required attribute will come, i am asking ValidationContext class,can you check the link i posted in my question.I was trying to implement same validation logic my wcf.but i am not finding namespace for ValidationContext